# Handling :DOWN and #Reference<...> messages after Task timeout

Tags: elixir

I'm spawning a function with `Task.async/3` and get the result with `Task.yield/2` with a timeout. When the function completes, the calling process receives two messages:

```
{#Reference<0.2781211517.3250323457.144521>, the_result_of_the_function}
```

where the`#Reference` is the reference of the monitor returned by `Task.async/3`, and

```
{:DOWN, #Reference<0.2781211517.3250323457.144521>, :process, #PID<0.24500.0>, :normal}
```

which is sent by the monitor to inform that the monitored process (the task) has shutdown.

If the task finishes *before* the timeout, `Task.yield/2` takes these messages out of the mailbox and returns the proper result. However, if the task finishes *after* the timeout, `Task.yield/2` returns `nil` and the program flow is already somewhere else when these two messages arrive.

I implemented two `handle_info` handlers to get these messages out of the mailbox. Yet, it's probably a bad idea because as I have no way to get only messages from expired tasks, (I don't see any way to "register" the `#Reference` of the task that has timeout-ed), I will probably remove valid massages before they are read by `Task.yield/2`.

What am I missing and how to get around this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.4/Task.html#yield/2) suggests the following approach:

> If the time runs out before a message from the task is received, this function will return `nil` and the monitor will remain active. […] If you intend to shut the task down if it has not responded within timeout milliseconds, you should chain this together with `shutdown/1`, like so:
>
> ```
> case Task.yield(task, timeout) || Task.shutdown(task) do
>   {:ok, result} ->
>     result
>   nil ->
>     Logger.warn "Failed to get a result in #{timeout}ms"
>     nil
> end
> ```

Comment: Grrr RFTFM! A though: as the `Task.yield(task, timeout) || Task.shutdown(task)` isn't atomic nothing prevents the scenario: 1/ `Task.yield()` timeouts, 2/ the scheduler gives some time to the async task to finish who sends the messages, 3/ `Task.shutdown()` executes but there is nothing anymore to shutdown and as a result, the mailbox of the calling process get eventually full. This probably holds even more for `Task.yield_many()` (which is my actual use case) as there is more processing (more async tasks) which increases the probability to get interrupted by the scheduler. Is this correct?

Comment: RTM again, it states that „[Using this approach] ensures that if the task completes after the timeout but before shutdown/1 has been called, you will still get the result, since shutdown/1 is designed to handle this case and return the result.“ ;-)

Comment: There‘s also an example in the docs how to apply Task.shutdown when using Task.yield_many: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.6.4/Task.html#yield_many/2-example